# ORA-00936 Missing expression on ROW NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle

I've checked linked questions and still haven't found an answer.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT contract_number,
           ROW NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contract_number
                              ORDER BY ID) RowNumber
   FROM contracts ) a
WHERE a.RowNumber = 1
```

This code throws ORA-00936 error. It underlines ROW NUMBER(), what's missing here?

Comment: `row_number()` not `row number()`

Comment: You have missed underline sign "_" in [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function.

Comment: woow what a shame, thank you guys...

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the syntax right for row number? It should be ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 0):

in the **4th line** **ROW NUMBER()** i used and in the last line you are using WHERE a.**RowNumber = 1**

the function name differ from each other 
this is the only error